# Convert a 3d array to a matrix with indices and value in each row

Tags: r

I have a large 3d array in R and I want to convert it to a matrix where the indices of each entry are in the first 3 columns and the corresponding value is in the fourth column. I want to do this efficiently (hence I don't want to use a bunch of for-loops) and I also want to exclude all zero entries from the matrix.

```
sample3dArray = array(rbinom(1000, 3, .1), c(10,10,10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this will compete effectively with `melt` if measured in terms of efficiency, despite my love of `melt` for its simplicity:

```
 cbind( which( sample3dArray>0, arr.ind=TRUE), sample3dArray[sample3dArray>0] )
```

It also has the virtue of actually returning a matrix which I doubt you would get from `melt`. (As well as removing the 0 entries which `melt` did not automagically provide (although it would be almost trivial to add a selection rule with "[".).

Answer (score 2):

From the `reshape2` package use `melt`:

```
library(reshape2)

sample3dArray = array(rbinom(1000, 3, .1), c(10,10,10))
melt(sample3dArray)
```